# GCP VPC IPv6 routing to an OpenVPN instance

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, ipv6, gcp

Previously, on premises, I successfully setup an OpenVPN server (on Ubuntu) that assigned globally routable IPv6 addresses to VPN clients (which is a project requirement). A generous /48 IPv6 prefix was routed on premises to the OpenVPN server, which could then subdivide it and allocate to VPN clients at will.

Now I wanted to move that OpenVPN server to GCP, and hopefully use IPv6 prefixes allocated by GCP. I launched a GCP Compute Engine VM instance where I am running an OpenVPN server on Ubuntu. Everything appears to be fine in the VM instance itself, but I am struggling to get a GCP VPC to route a suitable IPv6 prefix to the VM instance.

I experimented with a few scenarios with a VM instance with one or two NICs, one or two VPCs with peering, and a few globally routable /64 subnets (allocated by GCP), but in every scenario I got errors when trying to create a VPC “[route](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#adding_and_removing_routes)” (routing table entry) that routed a subnet range (e.g. /64) to my OpenVPN VM instance. For example, in one of the scenarios I got the following error message:

```
$ gcloud beta compute routes create <route-name> \ 
  --project=<project-name> --network=<vpc-name> --priority=1000 \
  --destination-range=<dest-prefix>/64 \ 
  --next-hop-instance=<instance-name> \ 
  --next-hop-instance-zone=<zone-name>

Creating route "<route-name>" failed. Error: Operation type [insert] failed with message
"<dest-prefix>/64 hides the address space of the network (<dest-prefix>/64).
Cannot change the routing of packets destined for the network."
```

Where `<dest-prefix>/64` is an IPv6 prefix such as 2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 that GCP had allocated to a VPC subnet, and which I had hoped to “borrow” for OpenVPN to assign to VPN clients. The error above would happen with longer prefixes too (e.g. /96), which prevented me from subdividing a /64 prefix. The error would not happen with shorter prefixes such as /63, but I could not really use shorter prefixes because it would encompass a range that was not allocated to my VPC (i.e. I’d be incorrectly routing someone else’s network).

The VM instance had the [canIpForward](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes) property set to ‘true’, so the lack of this property would not be the reason for the error.

The error message above actually makes some sense. I think that my problem would easily be solved if the VPC had a globally routable /48 prefix or even a /63 prefix (two consecutive /64 prefixes) allocated to it that could be routed to subnets. However, from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/subnets#ipv6-specifications), it appears that GCP only allocates globally routable /64 IPv6 prefixes to VPC subnets. There is the option of a /48 [ULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address) prefix, but that’s not globally routable so it does not meet the project requirement.

Does this mean that it is simply not (currently) possible to use GCP Compute Engine to host an OpenVPN VM instance that assigns globally routable IPv6 addresses to VPN clients? (With globally routable IPv6 addresses allocated by GCP, excluding things like hybrid subnets that connect on premises subnets to the VPC.)